# How to give value to object propety/field on the basis of that field name in java

Tags: java

I have a following class

```
public class TransactionDetails {

    public String title;
    public String type;
    public String num;
    public String name;
}
```

Now i have object of this class`and a string variable

```
   TransactionDetails  obj = new TransactionDetails ();
   String fieldType= "name";
```

value could also be "type", "num" or "title".
Now i want to assign some value to only that object field which name matches fieldType value. For example something like this

```
obj.fieldType = "Some Thing";
```

or

```
obj[fieldType] = "Some Thing";
```

I know this is wrong way. So is there any way to do that?

Comment: check out on [reflection](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/) api

Comment: @Atif Shahzad - It seems like you might be looking for an enum

Comment: I'm unclear on what you're trying to do here. The obvious way to assign values would be obj.name = "Some Thing". Please provide some more context on your question.

Comment: There are several ways to do this. But why do you want to do it? Where does the String value come from? Why is the value a String rather than an instance of a more useful class? I suspect you have an XY Problem here.